# Prove that the fusion/crossing matrix was a function of $c,h$ only and was invariant between different theories

Tags: definition, conformal-field-theory

The fusion matrix or crossing matrix
$$
F_{nm}\begin{bmatrix}i&j\\k&l\end{bmatrix}
$$
relates the 4 point correlation function in the different channels.

How to show that it was was a function of $c,h$ only, and, especially, for the fixed $c,h$, it was the same even for the different theories?

Answer (score 2):

The fusion matrix does not relate 4pt functions, it relates conformal blocks. It is a property of the chiral symmetry algebra, not of a given theory. You may think of it as a generalization of the modular S-matrix.

In the case of the Virasoro algebra, the fusion matrix depends on the central charge $c$ (a property of the algebra) and on six representations of the Virasoro algebra. If these representations are Verma modules, then the matrix depends on their conformal dimensions $h$. If however the representations are not Verma module (for example, logarithmic representations), then the matrix depends on their structures.